# How do I get a make file to output all files to a build directory?

Tags: windows, makefile

I'm trying to create a make file for a c++ project, and I want it to put all of the object files into a directory called build. The c++ files are in a directory called src. This is the current make file that I have.

```
SRCDIR = src
BUILDDIR = build
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -Iinclude
LDFLAGS = -Llib -lraylib -L. -ltolk

SRCFILES = $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.cpp)
OBJECTFILES = $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp, $(BUILDDIR)/%.o, SRCFILES)
EXECUTABLE = $(BUILDDIR)/earplanes.exe

all: $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTFILES)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@

$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
    mkdir $(subst /,\,$(@D))
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rmdir /s $(BUILDDIR)
```

This is on windows, hence the way I do the make and removing of directories. The error that I'm getting right now from this is:
make: *** No rule to make target `SRCFILES', needed by` build/earplanes.exe'.  Stop.
If someone could figure out what is going on, that would be very helpful.

Comment: Typo: `$(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp, $(BUILDDIR)/%.o, SRCFILES)` should be `$(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp, $(BUILDDIR)/%.o, $(SRCFILES))`.  Exactly as the error message tells you: you are using the static string `SRCFILES` here not the variable reference `$(SRCFILES)`